# How to edit the list of recent categories?

Tags: outlook, categories

Outlook Categories has 15 recently used lists.
Is there any way to edit this?
[image]

Older project's categories are included in the list.
I want to display new projects.

I would like to do this because it takes less time to select from this list than it does to select "All Categories" and then choose one.

I tried to print the master category list, but the flags in the displayed list don't seem to exist.
https://www.slipstick.com/developer/print-list-categories-colors/

Answer (score 0):

There is no information how Outlook maintains the recent categories list. But I think this information could be stored in the same place with categories list. Check out the associated content of your Inbox folder. Read more about that in the [Outlook Categories and Color Categories](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/outlook-categories-and-color-categories/) article.

Also I've noticed that categories that were added using Group Policy (by adding corresponding windows registry keys) are displayed first:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\nn.0\outlook\preferences
String: newcategories
Value: New Category 1; New Category 2
```

The same path in the CURRENT_USER hive also works.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\nn.0\Outlook\Preferences
String: newcategories
Value: New Category 1; New Category 2
```

Finally, you may consider using shortcuts for categories, so you shouldn't care about the recent categories list.